# Titanium window + remove method

Tags: javascript, android, titanium, titanium-mobile

I have a defined a window like this.

```
var fenetreBase = Titanium.UI.createWindow({...});
```

this window can display 3 views which I'm adding like so

```
fenetreBase.add(vueimage.vue);
fenetreBase.add(vuegraphe.vue);
```

etc.

Currently, when I want to change the displayed view, I'm forced to remove all (even those who are not add).

```
fenetreBase.remove(vuegraphe.vue);
fenetreBase.remove(vueimage.vue);
```

Is there a simple way to do something like the example below?

```
 fenetreBase.remove(this.view); // which would be very cool.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could keep a hold of the current view and then have a function that handles the add/remove actions.

```
var currentView = null;

function replaceView(view) {
    if(currentView) {
       window.remove(currentView);
       currentView = null;
    }

    currentView = view;
    window.add(currentView)
}
```

Then when you find out which view to show you just call the function.

```
replaceView( viewToShow );
```